# loading overlay for long javascript runtime on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, dom

I have a callback function which is triggered on a button click event. The callback function has to do a lot of DOM manipulation on the page without a submit or an ajax request.

The DOM manipulation refer to an data table with a lot of rows. To give a feedback to the user I want to show a loading overlay (jquery plugin mask) on the data table. The result of DOM manipulation is that selected rows from the data table are transmitted to another data table.

The problem is what die loading overlay is not showing immediately because the browser stops the `javascript` execution for a few seconds and then start processing the loading overlay and DOM manipulation within a moment. The result is that the DOM manipulation is correct executed but the user do not see the loading overlay while processing.

When I insert an `alert()` before executing the DOM manipulation I can see the loading overlay.

I don't have a glue why the loading overlay is not showing immediately.

Here is the code for the callback function:

```
var callback = function(functionGuid, callbackFunctionName, tablename) {
    FUNCTION_TABLE_UTIL.showLoadingOverlay(tablename);
    executeCallback(functionGuid, callbackFunctionName, tablename);
    FUNCTION_TABLE_UTIL.hideLoadingOverlay(tablename);
};
```

Comment: try to call executeCallback in some timeout callback with for example 5 seconds to see if your loading overlay was shown successfully

Comment: I tried 'var callback = function(functionGuid, callbackFunctionName, tablename) {
        FUNCTION_TABLE_UTIL.showLoadingOverlay(tablename);
        setTimeout(function() {
            executeCallback(functionGuid, callbackFunctionName, tablename)
        }, 5000);
        FUNCTION_TABLE_UTIL.hideLoadingOverlay(tablename);
    };' The loading overlay is not showing immediatly ...

Comment: The loading overlay is invoked by `var showLoadingOverlay = function(selector){
        if (typeof selector === 'undefined' || !selector) {
            selector = '#' + FORM.getMainFormId();
        }
        $(selector).mask(MESSAGES.i18n('gui.loadingOverlay'));
    };`